# Why isn't my mock getting used in my minitest test run?

Tags: mocking, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest, stub

I'm trying to write a test with Rails 5 and using minitest  Here is my test code ...

```
@client = Coinbase::Wallet::Client.new(api_key: ENV['COINBASE_KEY'], api_secret: ENV['COINBASE_SECRET'])
sell_price = 4000
assert sell_price > last_buy_price * (1 + MoneyMakerThreshhold.find_buy.pct_change)
@client.stub :sell_price, "USD" do
  {"base"=>"BTC", "currency"=>"USD", "amount"=>"#{sell_price}"}
end

svc = CryptoCurrencyService.new
svc.sell(last_transaction)
```

but when it esxecutes on the below what is printing out is not my mocked sell price of "4000", it is the actual sell price being returned by the client ...

```
  def sell(last_transaction)
    client = Coinbase::Wallet::Client.new(api_key: ENV['COINBASE_KEY'], api_secret: ENV['COINBASE_SECRET'])
    sell_price = client.sell_price(currency: 'USD').amount
    puts "buy: #{last_transaction.btc_price_in_usd} sellprice: #{sell_price} last:#{last_transaction.btc_price_in_usd}"
```

How do I get my mock worked into things?

Comment: Which version of coinbase-ruby do you use?

Answer (score 0):

[Object#stub](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/4.2.0/Object:stub) stubs method value for duration of the block, as documentation states

> Add a temporary stubbed method replacing name for the duration of the block. If val_or_callable responds to #call, then it returns the result of calling it, otherwise returns the value as-is. Cleans up the stub at the end of the block.

Answering to your original question:

```
client.stub :sell_price, {"base"=>"BTC", "currency"=>"USD", "amount"=>"#{sell_price}"} do
  svc = CryptoCurrencyService.new
  svc.sell(last_transaction)  
end
```

Comment: Hope you get this comment as I'm responding a little late.  Are you sayhing replace the code I have that begins with "@client.stub ..." with what you have provided?

Comment: @Dave yes. And put your assertion and puts statements into the block